# Differential Equation with Delta Dirac

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

This is my first question, and it was my last solution, since no article could help me solve this differential equation.

The equation is in the following form:

$$\dfrac{d^2 f(x)}{dx^2}-Af(x)+B\delta(x-C)f(x) = 0 \quad x \in [0,L]$$ where $$\delta(x-C)= \infty\quad if \quad x=C$$or$$ \delta(x-C)=0 \quad if\quad x\neq C$$

What I'm Asking is the solution of $f(x).$

Ignoring the delta results in Exponential solutions, but delta function makes it difficult to calculate $f(x)$

P.S. : Had Kronecker instead of Dirac, which was TOTALLY wrong, that's why the 1st comments are kind of "strange" now.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is: solve differential equation $$\dfrac{d^2 f(x)}{dx^2}-Af(x)= 0$$ with initial condition $f(C) = 0$.

Comment: Yeah, but this doesn't really provide much. And the solution should provide the "General solution" with the Exponential  for the limit $C \rightarrow 0$ which has no such restriction @GEdgar

Comment: The solution will just ignore the Kronecker delta altogether which will make it a nonclassical solution to the given equation unless $f(C)=0$. A single value of x cannot affect a differential equation unless distributions like the Dirac delta arise.

Comment: @Ian It can't ignore the delta because this way for $x=C$ will get $f(C)=0$ which is an extra unwanted initial condition. Note that General solution doesn't provide this. (I can write them analytically on my answer if someone thinks it's non-trivia)

Comment: No, it ignores the delta and in effect ignores the point $x=C$ altogether which is why I said the solution is nonclassical without some additional requirement like you mentioned. Think about the trivial ODE $y'=0$ vs. $y'=\delta(x)$ (Kronecker sense), does the Kronecker delta do anything after you integrate it or do you just get the same answer in both cases?

Comment: Well, look. This is about string waves. Adding a "Point mass" on your [0,L] String, does include a delta function but no additional information.  (Mass included is the Β constant, and C is the x you place the mass) And so, no additional requirements should be added. @Ian

Comment: @user174411 point masses are dirac deltas, not kronecker deltas.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Oh god, I think you are right.

Comment: @Ian You are absolutely right and this is my fault. It was DIRAC not Kronecker :(. Changed the Question, Massive fault, really sorry

Comment: I figured since you specifically were excluding the Dirac delta that you meant to do so, even though I couldn't understand how that could be the case because that couldn't possibly do anything meaningful. But now that you've spelled out the physics of interest, yes, your delta is the Dirac delta not the Kronecker delta.

Comment: @Ian And to think, that I was very careful to choose which Delta should I choose... Truly apologize for the inconvenience. Now I need to find $f(x)$ with that Dirac delta...

Comment: Νope, this is actually the case of T const and $\mu$ const. What you actually have, using Lagrangian method, is $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}( \rho (x) \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}) - \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} T \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}$$ and using $$\phi =f(x)g(t)  $$ results in the upper equation for $f(x)$ - T is constant, only mass density change -  @spaceisdarkgreen

Comment: Now with the dirac correction Im sure that  this is the equation that needs solution. Just that, since is Math stack Exchange, I didn't post all the "physics" work I ve done. @spaceisdarkgreen

Comment: @Ian Do you have ANY idea on how to proceed? :(

Comment: If the boundary conditions are initial conditions, then the Laplace transform should make the problem relatively trivial. If they are instead boundary conditions, the point is that the delta function term creates a jump in $f'$ at $x=C$ whose size is $-Bf(C)$, while preserving the continuity of $f$ itself. So you can solve the problem with $f'(0),f'(L)$ as parameters, run those from $x=0$ to $x=C$ and $x=L$ to $x=C$, and then solve the equations $\lim_{x \to C^-} f(x)=\lim_{x \to C^+} f(x),\lim_{x \to C^+} f'(x)=-Bf(C)+\lim_{x \to C^-} f'(x)$ for $f'(0),f'(L)$.

Comment: You may want to look up solution of schrodinger eqn in delta function potential, common in introductory quantum mechanics books. The eigenvalue equation is the same as the one you wrote down (except the bcs at the endpts). Not positive how helpful it'll be or if you've already looked there, but it will outline how it produces a kink like ian says.

Comment: Really thank you all!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\delta(x-C) \, f(x) = f(C) \, \delta(x-C)$ so the equation can be written
$$f''(x) - A f(x) = -B f(C) \, \delta(x-C). \tag{1}\label{1}$$

Therefore solve $f''(x) - A f(x) = 0$ on the two intervals $[0,C)$ and $(C,L]$ and then "connect" the solutions so that $f$ is continuous but $f'$ has a step at $C$ such that $\eqref{1}$ is satisfied.

Comment: Much appreciated help!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is meant to be a sort of "singular potential" problem? That is, it's intended to be equivalent to something like $(\Delta-\lambda)u=\delta_c$ on an interval containing $c$? Assuming so, this equation is readily solved by Fourier transforms.